# Typescript, Angular Material, get and set accessor must have the same datatype

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

After installing @angular/material version^13.1.1. I have a lot of Typescript errors (2307) :

> 'get' and 'set' accessor must have the same datatype.

I have used

```
ng add @angular/material
```

example in \node_modules@angular\material\checkbox\checkbox.d.ts :

```
get disabled(): boolean;
set disabled(disabled: BooleanInput);
```

My Typescript version : ~4.5.2.

As far as I can see this cannot be resolved changing a parameter in tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be a bug on the version 13.1.1 of angular material. There is already a [bug issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24112) for that case reported.

I have checked the repo. Switching back to version 13.1.0 should fix your error until they provide some newer version with the issue fixed.

Comment: Thank you. I find it weird that they released this version overlooking this major problem...

Comment: @OleEHDufour check my solution. Hope it'll be helpful for both you.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to implement 'Angular Material datepicker' and run the below commands -

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
npm install --save @angular/animations
npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter
npm i moment
```

Then I have faced the same error ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32FHy.jpg)) at the time of `ng serve`.

If we look closely at the error, then we found that the error was coming from only `angular/cdk` and `angular/material`. E.g. -

angular/cdk -

> Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts:141:9 - error
> TS2380: 'get' and 'set' accessor must have the same type.
> 141     get enabled(): boolean;

angular/material -

> Error: node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/date-range-input.d.ts:48:9 - error
> TS2380: 'get' and 'set' accessor must have the same type.
> 48     get required(): boolean;

This is due to version incompatibility.

package.json -

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^13.2.2",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.3"
  }
```

---

## Solution -

Step 1 -

In my case, I was having:

```
"@angular/cdk": "^13.2.2",
"@angular/material": "^13.2.2"
```

In `package.json`, change the version of cdk and material. Save -

```
"@angular/cdk": "~12.2.13",
"@angular/material": "~12.2.13"
```

> Info - check [Angular Material website](https://material.angular.io/) to get different/other
> version.

[image: Angular Material version]

Step 2 -

Delete `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json`. Do `npm install` again.

---

## Result -

Project running or working successfully and no error at the time of `ng serve`.

[image: output]

Comment: This is a work around - my question pertains to version 13. But you are right, I had to downgrade as well.

Comment: This solution worked fine with me