# TypeScript errors online while it works on my machine : TS Version mismacth?

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-devops, ng-build

I'm trying to build an angular project on Azure DevOps. The build works using `ng build` on my Visual Studio machine.
Online, with the [Angular CLI Task](https://github.com/alexruizprado/azure-pipelines-angular-cli-task) it fails with lots of errors like this one that happens with ng-uikit-pro-standard:

```
ERROR in node_modules/ng-uikit-pro-standard/lib/free/buttons/radio.directive.d.ts:19:9 - error TS2380: 'get' and 'set' accessor must have the same type.

19     get uncheckable(): boolean;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~

ERROR in node_modules/ng-uikit-pro-standard/lib/free/buttons/radio.directive.d.ts:20:9 - error TS2380: 'get' and 'set' accessor must have the same type.

20     set uncheckable(value: BooleanInput);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is there a TS version mismatch between Azure and my machine ?

---

EDIT : I replaced the Angular CLI Task with a node one as MikeOne suggested, but the errors still remains.

Comment: Maybe this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70407048/typescript-angular-material-get-and-set-accessor-must-have-the-same-datatype

Comment: Everything should come from your package.json so a different version (of anything really) sounds a bit scary? I’m not sure what the AngularCli@ task does exactly, I always just use a normal NodeJs task and install ng cli as a step.

Comment: it fails the same with a simple NodeJS task :(

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved by upgrading to angular 13 and having dealt with another problem:

> TS2339: Property 'X' does not exist on type 'Y'

using

> // @ts-ignore

above the offending lines.